# Capture Current Frame in Video Player

Tags: roku, brightscript

I want to retrieve the current Video Frame and process it as an image when a video is paused. Is this possible in Roku Brightscript?

For Eg. I want to save the Paused Frame as Image and use it later as a Poster Image.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the Roku BrightScript SDK does not expose such functionality. I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score -1):

Yes - in Utilities page of the developer web interface click "Screenshot" button.

See the [documentation](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/Channel+Packaging+And+Publishing#ChannelPackagingAndPublishing-38GeneratingScreenshotsSincev31onRoku1andv43onRoku2) for details

Comment: I've not had any luck with taking screenshots in the video player. The rest of the screens in the app work fine, but the video player only results in fully black screenshots. Likely some sort of content protection mechanism.

Comment: You will not get the proper image screenshot during video play. You will get the blank image of black colour if you try to take screenshot from developer web interface during video play.

Comment: @SiekermanTechnology - or they are grabbing the image from an upper buffer. From what i remember, video is played at the "very bottom" and one had to punch alpha holes in overlays to see through. Might be unintentional that cant grab frame - thanks for the info though

Comment: Im pretty sure you will not get Video - if you want screenshot of video attache a capture card to a Roku2 analog outputs ;-)